# Error while installing php rar extension on ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu-20.04, php-extension

I am getting this error while installing php rar plugin on my ubuntu 20.04 server. how can i solve it?

```
root@root:/# free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            2000         870         113          36        1016         821
Swap:              0           0           0
```

`sudo pecl -v install rar`

```
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c: In function ‘_rar_get_archive_and_fragment’:
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c:787:66: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘zend_resolve_path’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  787 |                         zend_string *arc_str = zend_resolve_path(tmp_archive, tmp_arch_len);
      |                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                  |
      |                                                                  char *
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c:787:66: note: expected ‘zend_string *’ {aka ‘struct _zend_string *’} but argument is of type ‘char *’
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rar_stream.c:787:48: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_resolve_path’
  787 |                         zend_string *arc_str = zend_resolve_path(tmp_archive, tmp_arch_len);
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:215: rar_stream.lo] Error 1
rolling back 454 file operations
ERROR: `make' failed
```

PHP Version

```
root@root:/# php -v
PHP 8.0.22 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:40:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.22, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.22, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This looks like the RAR extension is incompatible with the PHP version you're using.

Comment: In the changelog of the 4.2 version of the rar plugin, it says that it has php8 support. I had php8.1 installed on my server and I downgraded to php8. the result did not change

Answer (score 3):

The `rar` extension in PECL only supports PHP 8.0, not PHP 8.1 which is the default version you'll get on Ubuntu 20.04, so if you have PHP/8.0, it *should* work for you, but your environment might have multiple versions of PHP installed now which can break your environment.

For you, you might have to fix all your `alternatives` to point to the correct versions (I assume you used `ppa:ondrej/php` to install the older PHP versions).

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/phpize-8.0
```

---

What follows is how to install the extension with either PHP 8.0 or 8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

---

### Installing `rar` on PHP 8.0

Here's proof it works on `php-8.0`, using a pristine environment and the version you can install from `ppa:ondrej/php`.

First we start with running a clean base container:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

And then run all the necessary package installs

```
# inside container
apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update

apt-get install -y php8.0 php8.0-dev php8.0-xml

pecl install rar
```

And this is the tail end of the install output:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0" install
Installing shared extensions:     /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr/lib/php/20200930/
running: find "/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0" | xargs ls -dils
183533087    0 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0
199246884    0 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr
200375743    0 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      17 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr/lib
201589234    0 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      22 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr/lib/php
202922222    0 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root      20 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr/lib/php/20200930
202922223 1964 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2010160 Sep  1 11:24 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserPcQEEc/install-rar-4.2.0/usr/lib/php/20200930/rar.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/rar.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/rar-4.2.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=rar.so" to php.ini
```

### Install `rar` with PHP 8.1

You can install the `rar` extension work with PHP 8.1, but you can't do it via pecl because `v4.2.0` of the plugin was released in December 2020 and doesn't support the API for PHP 8.1.

Instead, you have to manually install from the source code, using [`phpize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php).

Again, run the clean container:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

And then run all the necessary commands:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.1 php8.1-dev git

# Just to show that it's PHP 8.1
# root@e72cbf195c29:/# php -v
# PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 12:24:10) (NTS)

# Get the source code
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/cataphract/php-rar.git
cd php-rar

phpize

# phpize outputs that it's configuring for php8.1's API
# Configuring for:
# PHP Api Version:         20210902
# Zend Module Api No:      20210902
# Zend Extension Api No:   420210902

./configure && make && make install
```

And the build succeeds and the plugin's installed

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /root/php-rar/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/20210902/
```